# TextView Does Not Overlay VideoView Inside of FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-videoview

I am trying to have a `TextView` displayed on top (overlay) of a `VideoView`, and it is not happening.  I have the two elements inside of a `FrameLayout` with the TextView positions below the VideoView.  From my understanding, this is supposed to place it on top.

I have tried various ways of adding the TextView programmatically and removing the additional features of the VideoView e.g. onTouchListener().

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem or an explanation of overlaying views that could help me with this problem?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have posted code below:

activity_splash.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.androidtitan.hotspots.Activity.SplashActivity">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/splashVideo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/splashTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="placeholder text"
    android:textSize="60dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

SplashActivity.java

```
package com.androidtitan.hotspots.Activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.androidtitan.hotspots.R;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "hotspots";

TextView titleTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splashTitle);

    try{
        splashScreen();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //todo: we could display a picture here as an alternative
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e));
    }

    //this returns
    if(titleTextView.isShown()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "titleTextView.isShown()");
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "NOT SHOWN");
    }



}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}

public void splashScreen() {
    VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
    setContentView(videoHolder);
    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
            + R.raw.splash);
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
    videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            jumpMain(); //jump to the next Activity
        }
    });


    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    videoHolder.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels));

    videoHolder.start();

    videoHolder.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ((VideoView) v).stopPlayback();
            jumpMain();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private synchronized void jumpMain() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ChampionActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new VideoView instead of using the one in your XML layout and also calling setContentView which replaces the XML layout which loaded first with your new VideoView. That's why its failing. Do not call setContentView twice and change your code as below

```
public void splashScreen() {
    VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.splashVideo);

    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
        + R.raw.splash);
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
    videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            jumpMain(); //jump to the next Activity
        }
    });


    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    videoHolder.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels));

    videoHolder.start();

    videoHolder.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ((VideoView) v).stopPlayback();
            jumpMain();
        return true;
        }
    });
}
```